# How to find Missing Numbers in a table using sqlserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find Missing Numbers in a table..Table Like this.

```
   Sno                Branch 

    1                   ABC
    2                   ABC
    3                   ABC
    5                   ABC   // 4th sno is missing
    6                   ABC
    8                   ABC   // 7th sno is missing
   10                   ABC   // 9th sno is missing
```

I found the missing SNo using this Query

```
 ALTER proc [dbo].[K_RT_DCNoMissing]--1,50 
 as
 begin

 declare @id int
  set @id = 0
 declare @maxid int

 --set @id = @fromvalue
 select @maxid = (select count(*) dcno  from K_RT_Dailyentryretail nolock)   


create table #IDSeq
(
id int 
)

 while 0<@maxid--whatever you max is
 begin
insert into #IDSeq values(@id)

set @id = @id + 1
set @maxid = @maxid - 1
-- print @maxid
end

select 
s.id  
from 
#idseq s 
left join K_RT_Dailyentryretail t on 
    s.id = t.dcno 

  where t.dcno is  null  order by s.id asc

  drop table #IDSeq

  end
```

I am getting out put like this..

```
  MissingNo's
    4
    7
    9
```

Now I want to Display Sno with Branch Name like.

```
    MissingNo's           Branch
      4                   ABC
      7                   ABC
      9                   ABC
```

How can i get the branch name...

```
Am getting output as
4    abc
4    cde
4    fgh
7    abc
7    cde
7    fgh

but what actually am expecting is
4    abc
7    cde
.     ..
.     ..
```

etc.

Comment: how will you get the Branch name if there is no relation

Comment: how are you supposed to get the branch from a row that does not exists? btw the stor proc you post cannot work because of a inner select broken by a comment line.

Comment: If number is missing between, then alwasy GAP is only for 1 digit? Will this happen? like 1,2,3,6 ? after 3 GAP is there but next number is not 5, it is bigger than that. Will this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE to build a table of all the branches and the full range of numbers for each. Then left join that to the main table to find what is missing. This will allow you to get consecutive missing numbers, e.g. 3, 4 and 5 missing. You can adjust `@minid` and `@maxid` to whatever you want your range to be. If `@maxid` can be greater than 32767, then you will need to do something with batches of ranges.

```
declare @minid int, @maxid int

set @minid = 1
set @maxid = (select count(*) dcno from K_RT_Dailyentryretail with (nolock))

; with Branches as (
    select distinct Branch from K_RT_Dailyentryretail
)
, CTE as
(
    select @minid as Sno, Branch from Branches
    union all
    select Sno + 1, Branch from CTE where Sno < @maxid
)

select  CTE.Sno, CTE.Branch from CTE
    left outer join K_RT_Dailyentryretail k on k.Branch = CTE.Branch and CTE.Sno = k.Sno
where k.Sno is null
option (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13653/13

Comment: ; with Branches as (
    select distinct Branch from K_RT_Dailyentryretail  ...Here i get an error message like ..The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: am getting output as 1   abc,1   cde,1   cde. that means for one sno repeating the branch names.

Comment: k like any missing numbers. Those are coming for two branches

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that GAP between you number will be always of only 1 digit.
In this case following will work for you,

```
;With CTE as
(
select Sno,Branch,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Sno) R
 from C
)
select a.Sno+  1,a.Branch from CTE as a
left join CTE as b on a.R + 1= b.R 
where a.Sno + 1 <> b.Sno
```

One more thing is that, for missing row you want branch, I have thought that for missing row you want to  have branch of previous row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each branch has it's own set of sno numbers, this works:

```
select sno-1 as sno, branch
from t1
where sno-1 NOT in (select sno from t1 as t2 where t1.branch = t2.branch)
and sno > 1
;
```

Which you can check here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/daa81d/3

If sno is a unique key, let me know and I will revise the answer.

EDIT: Like AK47's answer, I'm assuming that the gap is only one row.